# Is it possible to keep Plymouth visible while X starts in the background?

Tags: boot, xorg, plymouth, raspberrypi

I'd like to keep the Plymouth boot screen visible while I start X in the background, and only switch to X (possibly running in another virtual terminal?) after a given wait period.

Since X starts in tty8, I've tried running the following immediately after starting it:

```
chvt 1 # change back to tty1
plymouthd
plymouth --show-splash
```

but there's a lot of flicker, the screen isn't fully repainted, and Plymouth falls back to text-only mode for some reason.

If it matters, I also use `nodm` to log the user in automatically and to start the X session, and the setup runs on a Raspberry Pi 3.

If there's something else that does the job better for overlaying graphics on the screen while the system/X server/my applications start, I'll of course be glad to hear!